# How to keep a variable unevaluated when used as parameter for `Sum`?

Tags: evaluation

Let's say I have assigned the follow value to `s` by

```
s = Floor[Log[n]]
```

Then I want to compute

```
Sum[r^j, {j, 0, s}]
```

but with `s` as a symbol, because otherwise the result is a bit difficult to read. But replacing `s` by `Hold[s]` and `HoldForm[s]` both fails to achieve what I want. `s` is always evaluated in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace it after Sum

```
Sum[r^j, {j, 0, s}]
```

> (-1 + r^(1 + s))/(-1 + r)

```
(-1 + r^(1 + s))/(-1 + r) /. s -> Floor[Log[n]]

(*(-1 + r^(1 + Floor[Log[n]]))/(-1 + r)*)
```

It's not recommend to directly use `=` , better in a `With` , or use `/.` instead.

Comment: Yeah, this could work. But I also want a way to remember what the value of `s` should be. I am not using two symbols `s` and `s0`. One used as symbol, the other as its value. Not perfect.